# Creating a bot that sends emails to a list of people on a specific date

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to create a bot that sends emails to a list of people on a specific date. I'm trying to figure out how to send it on a specific dates such as September 15th, November 15, etc.

Here is the code i'm currently working with:

```
from_address = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
to_address = ["emailaddress1", "emailaddresss2"]

subject = "Group Message Test Subject"
text = "Test message"
message = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, text)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(os.environ.get("username"), os.environ.get("password"))
print(server.sendmail(from_address, to_address, message))
print("Email sent to recipients")
server.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use any of the periodic task generating methods for handling the case, Check out some methods mentioned below.

1. `cron job` - Set up a cron job for running the script on a specific date.
2. `celery beat`  -  Celery has a scheduler called beat for doing the periodic task.
3. `Scraping Hub` - If you are using the code as a spider, deploy the code in scrapinghub and use the scheduler.

Comment: yes all of them, the last two are web services with support provided.you can view the running status via the web interface.